# A form on this page can not be clicked.

Tags: css

View this site with mobile, portrait mode with Iphone 6 settings:  https://glitties.com/

The "Keep me in the loop" form near the bottom can not be clicked.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following and your problem is solved:

```
.newsletterbox {
  z-index: 1;
}
```